# How to get contact details from contact number in android programatically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am working on call Application in android ,I have done most of things,But now i am working on call logs,I have made a call log,And i want to get all details of a contact from contact book,Using its number programatically,So in short how to get following details from contact book using contact number ,

```
-Name
-Email
-Photo
-Group
```

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrive contact details from phone number use following:

```
String number = "number to find";
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    String name = "?";

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

    try {
        if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
            contactLookup.moveToNext();
            name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
String email = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns.EMAIL));
        }
    } finally {
        if (contactLookup != null) {
            contactLookup.close();
        }
    }
```

> Note Add contact read permission to your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```